# Find all controls on a form, even those within Tab Controls - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, controls, ctype

I have a set of DataGridViews that are created at run time and I need to reference these to update them when changes are made.
I know that I can use

```
Dim dgvUpdate As DataGridView
dgvUpdate = CType(Me.Controls(strGridName), DataGridView)
```

to get hold of the datagrid I need and them re-run the SQL and re-do the DataGridView.DataSource.

However these DataGridViews are located within TabPages within any number of different TabControls and so do not appear in Me.Controls

Is there a way of being able, in code, to reference all controls within the current form, regardless of tabs, panels etc. that I can use in the Ctype method to grab the correct datagridview.

Comment: "I have a set of DataGridViews that are created at run time"  Since YOU are creating these controls, you could just store them in a `Dictionary(Of String, DataGridView)` so you can retrieve them again very quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method you can use to get every control on a form in Tab order:

```vb
Public Iterator Function GetControls() As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Dim ctrl = GetNextControl(Me, True)

    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
        Yield ctrl

        ctrl = GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop
End Function
```

If you wanted to use that to get every `DataGridView`:

```vb
For Each grid In GetControls().OfType(Of DataGridView)()
    'Use grid here.
Next
```

If you wanted to be more direct, this will get every `DataGridView` on any `TabPage` of a specific `TabControl`:

```vb
For Each grid In TabControl1.TabPages.
                             Cast(Of TabPage)().
                             SelectMany(Function(tp) tp.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)())
    'Use grid here.
Next
```

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney. I used the top code and cycled through until I found ctrl.name until I found the one I needed. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to cycle. If you wanted one control by `Name` then you can use `GetControls().OfType(Of DataGridView)().FirstOrDefault(Function(dgv) dgv.Name = someName)`. `If you know the name is valid then use `First` instead, in which case the result cannot be `Nothing`. That said, if you only want one control by name then use the other answer instead, as `Find` already does a search by `Name`. My code was written assuming that you wanted to access all of them. As I commented there though, why store the names when you can store the grids themselves?

Comment: I don't store the names as they are created. However they are all given a name that I can  build based on choices the user makes and then when the changes are completed the correct DGV is updated to reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can **recursively** search using [Controls.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=net-5.0).  This will find the control by name, no matter how deeply nested it is within other controls:

```
Dim dgvName As String = "dataGridView9001"
Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.Controls.Find(dgvName, True).FirstOrDefault
If Not IsNothing(dgv) Then
    ' ... do something with "dgv" ...
End If
```

Note the second parameter of `True` to the `Find()` call, telling it to search within children.

Comment: It seems that if you can store the names of the grids then you could just store the grids themselves instead, rendering such code pointless.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, Agreed.  Which is why I put that as a comment above on the original question.  Who knows what they're doing, though....

Comment: In a nut shell... because I hadn't thought of that at the time of writing the original code that produces the form. I will give it a go though.